# Copy from sheet 1 to sheet 2 when value is changed

Tags: vba, excel, range, copy-paste

So I'm running a macro that is web scraping a table after it preforms a search. it outputs the results, clears them, then runs the search with another.

I'm trying to copy part of the text that is outputted to a different sheet. without loosing any data.

My current code "recopies" each column every time a new row entry is entered. I only wish for it to copy in the cells that have a border.

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Columns("D:P")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Range("D" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Range("E" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Range("F" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Range("G" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) '
    Range("H" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("E" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Range("I" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("F" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Range("J" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("G" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Range("K" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("H" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Range("L" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("I" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Range("M" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("J" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Range("N" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("K" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Range("O" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("L" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Range("P" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("M" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice I didn't have the column labels in there. But thank you! I didn't know about the resize feature. And I was have trouble with the syntax of the intersect function. You solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it's impossible to know where the "cells that have a border" begin/end from your screenshot, since we can't see the row/column labels. But it sounds like you'll want to revise your `Intersect` statement to account for the specific range.

Right now, `Intersect(Target, Columns("D:P"))` means *any `Target` cell which is in columns D thru P, regardless of row*.

What you need is something like:

```
Intersect(Target, Range("D10:P1000"))
```

Which would fine-tune so that the `_Change` event handles only cells that change within the specified `Range("D10:P1000")`.

You can also use a *single* `.Copy` statement with the `.Resize` method:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ''## Modify the RANGE argument as needed 
    If Intersect(Target, Range("D10:P1000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Range("D" & Target.Row).Resize(1,13).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```

Here, the `.Resize` method says *take the range `Range("D" & Target.Row)` and make it 13 columns wide, which contains columns D thru P in `Target.Row`.

Comment: Nice work.  What do you think a `Intersect(Target, Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).CurrentRegion)`?

Comment: That might do it!!